# unique fixed point problem

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_{\ge0} \to \mathbb{R} $ where $f$ is continuous and derivable in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $|f'(x)| \le \frac{1}{2}$.

Prove that there exist only one $ x_{0}$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$.

Comment: Banach contraction principle.

Comment: if it's differentiable (not derivable), it must be continuous. no need to assume more

Comment: HInt : suppose they're is two different values $x_0$ and $x_1$, then consider $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$

Comment: Together with the mean value theorem

Comment: You don't need differentiable, just that $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition of rank less than one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$. We have that $g'(x)=f'(x)-1<-1/2<0$ and that $g(0)=1$. So $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing and $g(0)>0$, so there must me a unique $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)=0=f(x_0)-x_0$.

Remark: of course we have that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}g(x) = -\infty$

Comment: Upvoted, beat me to it.

Comment: will you please explain why should $g$ vanish at $x_0$

Comment: By intermediate value theorem: $g(0)=1$ so it's positive at $0$, and $g$ goes to $-\infty$ so it must intercept the $x$ axis at some point and thus vanish in that point. The unicity is given by the fact that $g$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Can you please explain why $g(x)\to -\infty $;I am not getting that

Comment: @learnmore the derivative is always less than -1/2, so the function has to go to $-\infty$

Comment: how can I prove that @JahanClaes

Comment: @learnmore Try the mean value theorem!

Answer (score 4):

Note that $1-{1 \over 2} x \le f(x) \le 1+ {1 \over 2}x$ and so
$f(x) -x \le 1-{1 \over 2}x$.

Hence $f(0) -0 = 1$ but for $x \ge 2$ we have $f(x) -x \le 0$. Hence there
must be some $x \in [0,2]$ such that $f(x) -x = 0$.

Now suppose $f(x_1) = x_1, f(x_2) = x_2$. Then 
$|x_1-x_2| = |f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \le {1 \over 2} |x_1-x_2|$ by the mean value
theorem, so we must have $x_1 = x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$ for $y>x$, then $$y-x=|f(y)-f(x)|=|\int_{x}^y f'(t)\mathrm{d}t|\leq \int_x^y |f'(t)|\mathrm{d}t<\frac{1}{2}(y-x),$$
a contradiction.

Comment: You need $f'$ to be Riemann integrable for this to work.

Comment: @copper.hat True.. I thought it follows from the compact domain $[x,y]$ and existence of $f'$ everywhere, but I see that it is not clear.

Comment: It is still a good initial approach to solving the problem.

Comment: And you can fix the approach by using the mean value theorem. For some $\xi \in (x,y)$ you have $f(y) - f( x) = (y-x) \, f'(\xi) \le \frac12 \, (y-x)$.